# PDF exported without ReportViewer has No Data - It is empty

Tags: c#, datagridview, pdf-generation, rdlc

I tried to export data in a `Datagridview` to a PDF file using the following code:

```
        LocalReport report = new LocalReport();

        ReportDataSource rds1 = new ReportDataSource(dt.TableName, dt);

        report.ReportPath = @"D:\Report1.rdlc";
                   report.DataSources.Add(rds1);

        byte[] data = report.Render("PDF");

        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(@"D:\output.pdf"))
        {               
            fs.Write(data,0, data.Length);
        }
```

Datatable '`dt`' has rows and columns with values.

I'm not doing anything with `Report1.rdlc` physically. Just added it to the project.

The output pdf file has no values displayed. It is just a blank page.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in the past. I solved it by using a report viewer created on the fly with its embedded `LocalReport`:

```
using (WinForms.ReportViewer reportViewer = new WinForms.ReportViewer()) {
    reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"D:\Report1.rdlc";

    ReportDataSource rds1 = new ReportDataSource(dt.TableName, dt);
    reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds1);

    reportViewer.refreshReport();

    byte[] data = reportViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF");

    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(@"D:\output.pdf"))
    {               
        fs.Write(data,0, data.Length);
    }
}
```

Note: code is untested, but it's more or less what I did and it worked pretty well.

Comment: No pal. It is still the same. The output pdf is of just 1KB with no data. :(